# What's the proper way to hit/consume APIs on AWS using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, angular-controller

I'm jumping aboard a new project, and building out an entirely new frontend in Angular. The existing project has RESTful APIs (on AWS) that the frontend application will be hitting.

In previous hobby projects, the setup has been:

- Client makes a GET request, which taps a function in Angular Controller
- Angular Controller validates elements of request, then calls Angular Factory
- Angular Factory takes request, and does $http.get to Express route
- Express route makes an actual request to outside API url, then returns response to Factory, which in turns passes response to Controller, and back to the frontend

Is this the proper way to architect something like this? Or should I be looking at a different type of setup to hit existing APIs on AWS?

Comment: Just make your Angular app talk to the API directly. Unless you have other reasons, there's no reason for an intermediary server (eg. Express in your example). The fact that the API is running on AWS has no real bearing this.

Comment: Seems like a no-brainer to call api directly unless there are CORS complications

Comment: @Sunil D. My reason for using Express previously was to handle some of the application routing, but it sounds like Angular's built-in routing now can handle that.

So should API calls be done from the Controller or from a Controller->Factory?

Comment: angular routing and API endpoints have really nothing to do with each other

Comment: @blunatic API requests can be made from literally anywhere: controllers, services/factories, or even directives. But realistically, you will want to use a service/factory b/c you can re-use the code and call the API from any part of your app.

Comment: @Sunil D. Got it, sounds like the way I've been managing API calls previously just complicates things by adding Express--but I should keep factories/services for reusability.

Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

If the API is RESTful, then you can simplify the interaction with it by using [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Unless you have a specific reason to be using the Express server (which you shouldn't if the AWS API is truly RESTful) then I don't see why you couldn't access the AWS API directly.